# How to show an added to cart notice in WooCommerce product loops

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display the “Added to cart” message on the product page, not on the individual product page.
When I click on the add to cart button the product is added to the cart, but there is no alert for the user that the product is already in the shopping cart.

I have tried this function, but it only modifies the message on the individual product page.

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'wps_custom_added_to_cart_message' );
 
function wps_custom_added_to_cart_message() {
    
    $message = 'You cool product is in the cart!' ;
    
    return $message;
    
}
```

Also note that the button has this class “button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart”.

I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: For Ajax add to cart jQuery is required, to show an added to cart message…

Comment: Thanks! not exactly what was required but it worked anyway.

Comment: This is just an example that shows you the way. It can be customized in an other way to show a classic woocommerce notice instead, but it requires some knowledge.